# How to properly process json with an array of images

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I'm new to C#, I can't figure out how to parse JSON with an array of images. Everywhere basic examples with one picture.
For example, if JSON is simple:

```json
{
  "Rem": 1,
  "name": "bandana for girls",
  "articul": "18033325",
  "Price": "1 332",
  "Pict":"https://public/shop/products/28/00/120028/images/174872/174872.932x1242.jpg"
}
```

Then I create a class:

```cs
public class PriceList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Rem { get; set; }

    public string Price { get; set; }

    public string articul { get; set; }

    public string Pict { get; set; }
}
```

And then I pass it to XAML:

```cs
this.BindingContext = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<PriceList>>(json);
```

But how to process if there is an array of pictures in JSON?:

```json
{
  "Rem": 1,
  "name": "bandana for girls",
  "articul": "1805033325",
  "Price": "1 332 ",
  "Pict": [
    "https://wa-data/public/shop/products/28/00/120028/images/174872/174872.932x1242.jpg",
    "https://wa-data/public/shop/products/84/08/120884/images/183097/183097.932x1242.jpg"
  ]
}
```

I can not find such an example anywhere, tell me kind people how to solve this problem?

Comment: you may want to tag your question with the c# tag.

Answer (score 1):

you can deserialize both your jsons using

```
 PriceList priceList=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PriceList>(json);
```

the only difference is that for the second json

```
 public string Pict { get; set; }
```

should be replaced by

```
 public List<string> Pict { get; set; }
```

if you don't know what json you will get, this class will be working for both

```
public class PriceList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Rem { get; set; }

    public string Price { get; set; }

    public string articul { get; set; }

    public List<string> Pict { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConstructor]
    public PriceList(JToken pict)
    {
        if (pict.Type.ToString() == "Array")
            Pict = pict.ToObject<List<string>>();
        else
        {
            Pict = new List<string>();
            Pict.Add(pict.ToString());
        }
    }

    public PriceList() {}
}
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!!!